# Is there anyway to delete the data points of a cloud watch metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

So when my instance will start it will create a alarm that will stop a machine if its CPU utilization is less than 20 for a particulate period of time.But problem is when next time I'm starting the same instance,based on the previous cloudwatch metrics's data points instance is again getting shutdown immediately.Is there any way to clear the data points of cloudwatch metrics or any other solution like to start the fresh period for alarm that does not depend on previous data points of cloudwatch metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better solution would be to, as a part of your startup procedure:

- [DisableAlarmActions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_DisableAlarmActions.html)
- Sleep until the old data points aren't relevant in your alarm's calculation.
- [EnableAlarmActions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_EnableAlarmActions.html)

These Disable/Enable Alarm Action calls are available via the API, CLI, and various SDKs. This solution should be preferable because you get what you want (disabling instance shut down for a period of time when it doesn't make sense to shut down) without losing that data if you ever need it for review, troubleshooting, etc.